# How to block users from closing a window in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, anti-patterns

Is it possible to block users from closing the window using the exit button <kbd>[X]</kbd>? I am actually providing a close button in the page for the users to close the window.Basically what I'm trying to do is to force the users to fill the form and submit it. I don't want them to close the window till they have submitted it.

I really appreciate your comments, I'm not thinking of hosting on any commercial website. Its an internal thing, we are actually getting all the staff to participate in this survey we have designed....

I know its not the right way but I was wondering if there was a solution to the problem we have got here...

Comment: Thank God the answer is no.

Comment: I don't want my window trying to force me to submit some form.
Killing the process of the browser is a way you will not be able to prvent with javascript

Comment: From a usability standpoint, what if the user doesn't want to fill out the form and leave/close the window for whatever reason? Won't that frustrate users on your site and drive them away? Or worse, enter in garbage data just to get the window to close?

Comment: Don't downvote because you find websites that do this distasteful.  Provide a constructive alternative with the hope that he'll see the benefits of doing it some other way.  The question is reasonable.

Comment: That's just not how the web works - this *shouldn't* be possible. Your app sends some HTML and Javascript to the user and then it is out of your hands. JavaScript thankfully doesn't have THAT much control over the client.

Comment: guys i really appreciate your comments,im not thinking of hosting on any commercial website.its an internal thing,we are actually getting all the staff to participate in this survey we are designing....

Comment: @manraj82: Many modern survey systems will be able to track the user's progress one page at a time. If the user aborts in the middle, they can resume just after the last stage they completed.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Take a look at [`onBeforeUnload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload).

It wont force someone to stay but it will prompt them asking them whether they really want to leave, which is probably the best cross browser solution you can manage. (Similar to this site if you attempt to leave mid-answer.)

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    function confirmExit() {
        return "You have attempted to leave this page. Are you sure?";
    }
</script>
```

**Edit: Most browsers no longer allow a custom message for `onbeforeunload`.**

See this [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=587940) from the 18th of February, 2016.

> onbeforeunload dialogs are used for two things on the Modern Web:

1. Preventing users from inadvertently losing data.
2. Scamming users.

> In an attempt to restrict their use for the latter while not stopping the former, we are going to not display the string provided by the webpage. Instead, we are going to use a generic string.

> Firefox already does this[...]

Comment: This will not work in Opera, as it doesn't fire onbeforeunload events.

Comment: Is opera a browser!!!! How can 1.6% people can use it!
http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

Comment: 1.6% people that don't get annoyed by dialogs asking if they want to close a window? Seriously considering converting to Opera and becoming part of the now 1.603%..

Comment: Firefox not showing any custom string message returned from confirmExit() function.

Comment: @FrancescoMM There are all kinds of possible reasons that you might want to confirm that a user wants to close a page so they don't do it by accident.

Comment: MDN docs about this one at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Comment: This doesn't work in firefox 59.0.2 and chrome 65.0.3325.181 now and how can I call a function when the page is closed?

Comment: There are some legitimate use for this. I am implementing an ethereum stream-base mentoring solution. If the user just close the window, he will lose money.

Comment: my legitimate use is we are allowing dispatchers to edit time card entries for the drivers and there is a ton of validation on that grid that is ran when the return button is clicked.  Just closing the tab will make it possible to break financial settlement.  I don't care about the ui aspect.   Money trumps pretty.

Comment: When unfinished to upload images, we need to tell the user not to close the tab.

Comment: Ahah [the only browser allowing for custom message](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#browser_compatibility) nowadays is IE! Geez, it's like the dude reaching for the party when everyone left.

Answer (score 17):

If you don't want to display popup for all event you can add conditions like

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    function confirmExit() {
        if (isAnyTaskInProgress) {
           return "Some task is in progress. Are you sure, you want to close?";
        }
    }
```

This works fine for me

Comment: I have tested it on IE8, Firefox and Chrome, it is working fine.

Answer (score 11):

What will you do when a user hits ALT + F4 or closes it from Task Manager

Why don't you keep track if they did not complete it in a cookie or the DB and when they visit next time just bring the same screen back...:BTW..you haven't finished filling this form out..."

Of course if you were around before the dotcom bust you would remember porn storms, where if you closed 1 window 15 others would open..so yes there is code that will detect a window closing but if you hit ALT + F4 twice it will close the child and the parent (if it was a popup)

Comment: First of all, of course this sort of "feature" should not be abused. There is always the possibility, that the action that needs to be confirmed/deferred is critical and/or time sensitive. For example, online banking. I submit a "billpay" transaction for a payment that needs to be initiated today. I am shown a review/confirmation page where I can `Edit`, `Confirm`, or `Cancel`. I switch to another browser tab and then inadvertently close the browser. I need the banking page to show and let me know that confirmation is required. Waiting until next week when I open billpay again is not ideal.

Answer (score 7):

This will pop a dialog asking the user if he really wants to close or stay, with a message.

```
var message = "You have not filled out the form.";
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
    var e = event || window.event;
    if (e) {
        e.returnValue = message;
    }
    return message;
};
```

You can then unset it before the form gets submitted or something else with

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```

Keep in mind that this is **extremely** annoying. If you are trying to force your users to fill out a form that *they don't want to fill out*, then you will fail: they will find a way to close the window and never come back to your mean website.

Comment: you have a type on line 3, it's supposed to be  `var e = event || window.event`

Answer (score 6):

How about that?

```
function internalHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // required in some browsers
    e.returnValue = ""; // required in some browsers
    return "Custom message to show to the user"; // only works in old browsers
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', internalHandler, true);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent('onbeforeunload', internalHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If your sending out an internal survey that requires 100% participation from your company's employees, then a better route would be to just have the form keep track of the responders ID/Username/email etc. Every few days or so just send a nice little email reminder to those in your organization to complete the survey...you could probably even automate this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are many pre-built survey systems that are already capable of this (not sure if they are a lot of $$, but that's another topic).

Comment: we were actually depending on this prebuilt survey system,but it has proved to be useless...so was thinking of an easier way of doing it,but anyway thanks for your comments....

Answer (score 3):

### theoretically, yes [[try the demo]](https://spectricso.github.io/spectric-samples/2229942/preventClose.html)

<sup>but please, please don't do this</sup>

With the [BroadcastChannel API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel) we can actually achieve, to some degree, a way to prevent the user from closing the tab.

This method relies on two conditions however:

- the user opens two instances of the page
- popups have not been disabled

Essentially, by injecting this snippet, we can prevent the user from closing *all instances* of the current page:

```js
const bc = new BroadcastChannel("close-channel");
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (e) => {
    bc.postMessage("close");
});

bc.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
    window.open(location.href, "_blank", "");
})
```

How this works is, when at least two instances of the page are open, if the user attempts to close one instance, it sends a message through the `BroadcastChannel` telling the other instance to open another instance of itself. Theoretically it is impossible to close all instances of the tab.

**However, this is an extremely dangerous method.** If the user attempts to close the window, the tabs will duplicate infinitely and crash the browser.

The only way to break out of this is to kill the browser or disable popups.

Comment: I liked the solution and the disclaimer.

Answer (score 1):

It's poor practice to force the user to do something they don't necessarily want to do.  You can't ever really prevent them from closing the browser.

You can achieve a similar effect, though, by making a `div` on your current web page to layer over top the rest of your controls so your form is the only thing accessible.

Comment: Ugh that's also extremely annoying. It's a great way to ensure I don't come back to a site.

Comment: It is annoying, I agree.  But it's better than forcing me to close my browser with a task manager.  I just close the annoying tab, instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the `window.onclose` event and return `false` in the event handler.

```
function closedWin() {
    confirm("close ?");
    return false; /* which will not allow to close the window */
}
if(window.addEventListener) {
     window.addEventListener("close", closedWin, false);
}

window.onclose = closedWin;
```

Code was taken from [this site](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/431659-gecko-dom-window-onclose-event).

In the other hand, if they force the closing (by using task manager or something in those lines) you cannot do anything about it.

Comment: then firefox is probably broken.  They are the only one that isn't chromum - derived, and our code for our site (as well as the library we paid for that we use) is full of special code to fix stuff so that it displays correctly in firefox.  Additionally I hope you didn't downvote this.  This answer is ten years old and it probably worked then.