# How can I ask users to confirm before leaving the page on the Aurelia.js

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have an long operation on the page. How can I said user wait a bit when he make the navigation change?

The idea is to show the promt dialog. But the trouble prevent default Aurelia router behavior.

How make it works in Aurelia.js?

Comment: Take a look to this previous asked querstion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704533/intercept-page-exit-event

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use the `canDeactivate` hook of your view-model. Like this:

```
canDeactivate() {
   return confirm('Are you sure you want to leave this page?');
}
```

*canDeactivate() - Implement this hook if you want to control whether or not the router can navigate away from your view-model when moving to a new route. Return a boolean value, a promise for a boolean value, or a navigation command.*

More information at http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.2.2/doc/article/cheat-sheet/7

Comment: It's only for navigating away, but what about closing browser window?

Comment: I suppose the answer is not specific to the Aurelia.js https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229942/how-to-block-users-from-closing-a-window-in-javascript

Comment: The question and the answer are specific to AureliaJS