# How can I ask users to confirm before closing the window with Aurelia.js app

Tags: javascript, aurelia

So I want to ask users to confirm that the want to leave the page before the browser is closed. I don't have problem showing the user message box when he is navigating away from the page, only when he's closing the window. This doesn't work for me:

`PLATFORM.global.addEventListener("beforeunload", this._beforeUnloadEventHandler);`

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37183838/how-can-i-ask-users-to-confirm-before-leaving-the-page-on-the-aurelia-js?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer only helps with navigating away.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
PLATFORM.global.addEventListener("beforeunload", () => this._beforeUnloadEventHandler());
```

Comment: It doesn't sadly :(

Comment: But maybe I'm not invoking it properly? I'm doing it in my viewmodels `activate` method. Is it the correct place?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how jquery event system works compared to `PLATFORM.global.addEventListener` but this is what I use.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', () => {
  if (this.dirty) {
    return 'Really leave?'; // return a string to ask the user. You can't stop it in any other way.
  }
});
```