# how to prevent a user close/leave a browser windows using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to prevent a user close/leave a browser windows using javascript/jquery..

If user open my web page then he can not close or minimizes or move to other window..

how to do this using javascript or Jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to block users from closing a window in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229942/how-to-block-users-from-closing-a-window-in-javascript)

Comment: i dont want to say this is user friendly. can you rethink about doing this on your web page. your user might get annoyed about this

Comment: This also has the answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser

Answer (score 4):

You can try this :

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = PopUpExit;
function PopUpExit() {
    return "You want to leave this page?";
}
</script>
```

Here is the code if you need only alert without text :

Javascript :

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
return '';
};
```

Jquery :

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
return '';
});
```

Comment: But there are an option to leave and stay....I do not want these option....

Comment: So you saying, page shouldn't close also it shouldn't show pop up ?

Comment: How do you expect to close the browser in this case ? since you don't want to minimize or close.

Comment: Any how i want user not able to close or minimizes window...alert box not a problem...but in alert box LEAVE option not show..

Comment: alert is ok, but without text in it ?

Comment: Let me know, this what you need.