# My requirement is that I want to show a message to user while closing the browser tab or window

Tags: javascript

I am trying using following code-

```
window.onunload = function(e){
return "Do you really want to quit without saving."
}
```

**

> But message is also appearing if I will try to navigate from one page
>   to another

**. I only want this functionality if user clicks on the [x] button not on any event change.

I have also tried following-

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
 return "Somethig"
}
```

Note- I want to identify the event when user only closing the browser, not for any other page event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to block users from closing a window in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229942/how-to-block-users-from-closing-a-window-in-javascript)

Comment: I want an explanation for detecting that event is only called for [x] buttons not from page navigation....coz page navigation also trigger these events.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
   //your code
});
```

using javasscript:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
    var displaymessage = 'Are you sure?';
    e = e || window.event;

    if(e)
        e.returnValue = displaymessage;

    return displaymessage;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This question is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own).

> You can't modify the default dialogue for `onbeforeunload`, so your best bet may be to work with it.

Also, in recent versions of Chrome, the feature has been deprecated.

> **Edit 09/04/2018**: custom messages in onbeforeunload dialogs are deprecated since chrome-51 (cf: release note)