# How do I prevent a script from closing the window/tab in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm debugging an SSO app and I need to prevent the window from closing so I can inspect the requests and responses. I tried to disable Javascript but the login flow requires Javascript. Network > Preserve Log doesn't work either. Pinning the tab didn't work either. There are several redirects before it closes. I do not have access to the code of the SSO server. How can I prevent a script from closing the window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to do it by opening the link in an Incognito Window. When it tried to close itself, Chrome gave the warning

> Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.

[image]

I didn't have a script open the window in the first place. Instead I was using `target="_blank"`, but Chrome may have equated that with a script. (`window.opener` was set.)

Comment: Cool!  Thank you for sharing the solution. Please "accept" your answer!

Answer (score 0):

See if these links help:

[how to block users from closing a window in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229942/how-to-block-users-from-closing-a-window-in-javascript)

Take a look at onBeforeUnload.

It wont force someone to stay but it will prompt them asking them whether they really want to leave, which is probably the best cross browser solution you can manage. (Similar to this site if you attempt to leave mid-answer.)

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    function confirmExit() {
        return "You have attempted to leave this page. Are you sure?";
    }
</script>
```

This link might also apply to your specific use case:

[Prevent script opened windows from closing them](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/prevent-script-opened-windows-from-closing-them/24560)

Comment: That is pretty much the opposite of what I want. That is to programatically prevent a user from closing a tab, while I want to manually prevent a script from closing the tab.

Comment: I tried `window.close = function(){}` but the `window` object is reset after the first redirect.