# Open a Modal when closing browser tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.onunload

Want to open a modal when closing browser tab. Tried `window.onbeforeunload` , `window.unload` but not working. Any Other Solution with JavaScript or jQuery?

```
    <script>
        window.onbeforeunload = modal;

        function modal() {
        return 'leaving';
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: post some code here

Comment: check this if it could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229942/how-to-block-users-from-closing-a-window-in-javascript

Comment: Set the module to open first the create a function to close the browser when the module closes

Comment: Answer here [link] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's forbidden.In modern browsers, any action want to stop closing window is impossible.

some actions such as `window.showModalDialog()`, `window.alert()`, `window.confirm()`,`window.prompt()` are ignored in `onunload` or `onbeforeunload` event.

And, if u can do these actions, means you can make the browser can't be closed. it's dangerous for users