# How to prevent users from leaving the site with the an exit popup? JS

Tags: javascript, event-handling, mouseevent

I want to be able to have a copy of my website to reappear every time the user tries to leave the site. Is there such a method/event handler?

No need to mention the bad UI, I just want to explore more with event handlers

Comment: No can do...... You can ask them not to leave, nothing that prevents them from leaving the site.

Comment: So you mean adware?

Comment: Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload

Comment: similar to adware, but not with ads, just want a copy of the website to reappear

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `onbeforeunload` event.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
   return 'Are you sure that you want to leave this page?';
};
```

Comment: And that will keep them from leaving how?

Comment: It will show a popup

Comment: But you can still leave

Comment: I guess there is no way of blocking someone from leaving your website

Comment: This is no longer possible in modern browsers. See: [_"How to block users from closing a window in Javascript?"_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2230056/1762224)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to prevent a user from leaving your website, let alone spawn a new tab upon them exiting.

Here is a similar question that discusses why this is a bad idea and why most modern browsers have since removed this ability:

> [*"How to block users from closing a window in Javascript?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2230056/1762224)

The example below is the purely theoretical:

```html
<!html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Persistent Page...</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function closeHandler(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Does not actually cancel
        e.returnValue = ''; // Does prevent dialog (doesn't show anyways)
        alert('Leaving website, opening a new tab...'); // Does not display
        window.open(window.location.href, '_blank'); // Open a new tab?, No...
      }

      if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', closeHandler, true);
      } else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent('onbeforeunload', closeHandler);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Persistent Page...</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```